# Installing error of mongodb in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, mean-stack

I installed mongodb in my ubuntu and then when i run it i got active but after that i uninstalled it,then again i installed ,then when i start it i am getting error as

```
 ● mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; disabled; vendor preset:
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-02-14 14:11:21 IST; 21s ago
  Process: 1314 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (cod
 Main PID: 1314 (code=exited, status=14)
```

Can anyone please help me thanks.

Comment: Which version of mongodb do you have?

Comment: 2.6.10 .................

Comment: Did you try to install the newest version (3.4) and check if the error persists?